# Merge existing PDF files into a single file, and add a clickable TOC [Reportlab, Python]

Tags: python, pdf, merge, reportlab, tableofcontents

I'm trying to merge several existing PDF files into a single one.
The tricky part comes when trying to add a table of contents that link to the first page of every merged pdf file.

I tried to generate a separate pdf with a ToC and then merging with the other files, but this breaks the links/bookmarks.

I also tried to add the PDF files while generating the ToC, but I can't add an existing PDF to the flowable.

The next questions seem to relate to this, but the answers don't really apply to this case, or some I haven't been able to use to solve this with that solution.

[Clickable TOC with x of y page numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041397/python-reportlab-clickable-toc-with-x-of-y-page-numbering)

[Create outlines/TOC for existing PDF in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157456/create-outlines-toc-for-existing-pdf-in-python)

[Merge existing PDF into new reportlab pdf via flowables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368545/merge-existing-pdf-into-new-reportlab-pdf-via-flowables)

Thanks

Comment: I believe you can do this sort of thing with the paid version of ReportLab, though I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1):

I have used **PDFsam** to do this task; it is free and open-source, and it can be used to generate a clickable table of contents that is automatically generated either based on the file name or the document title.