# Issue creating an interactive table of contents using links [Python's FPDF package]

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf, pypdf, tableofcontents

I am trying to create table of contents using **Python's FPDF package** (https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I want the table of contents to be at the top of the PDF document, and clickable so that the reader is instantly taken to a section.

**The issue I have is that for the links to work, the table of contents needs to be at the end of the document.**

I have tried using python's **PyPDF2** to split the created PDF document and move the table of contents to the beginning of the document. The problem is that in the resulting PDF the links no longer work.

I am using python (v3.7) with Spyder.

Here is my code for creating the table of contents:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

# This is my section with link to table of contents
report.add_page(orientation='p')
report.set_font('Helvetica', size=22, style ='B')
report.cell(200, 10, 'section', 0, 2, 'l') 
DD = report.add_link()
report.set_link(DD)

# Table of contents including that one section
report.write(5, 'Section',DD)
```

Here is my code for rearranging the PDF document (TOC = table of contents):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter, PdfFileMerger

PDF_report = PdfFileReader('file.pdf')
pdf_bulk_writer = PdfFileWriter()
output_filename_bulk = "bulk.pdf"
pdf_TOC_writer = PdfFileWriter()

output_filename_TOC = "TOC.pdf"

for page in range(PDF_report.getNumPages()):
    current_page = PDF_report.getPage(page)
    if page == PDF_report.getNumPages()-1:
        pdf_TOC_writer.addPage(current_page)
    if page <= PDF_report.getNumPages()-2:
        pdf_bulk_writer.addPage(current_page)

# Write the data to disk
with open(output_filename_TOC, "wb") as out:
     pdf_TOC_writer.write(out)
     print("created", output_filename_TOC)       

# Write the data to disk
with open(output_filename_bulk, "wb") as out:
     pdf_bulk_writer.write(out)
     print("created", output_filename_bulk)   

pdfs = ['TOC.pdf', 'bulk.pdf']

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Comment: Take a look at a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157456/create-outlines-toc-for-existing-pdf-in-python